# ALignment issue for Replied View in layout Like WhatsApp

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying make Replied view UI like whatsapp --> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ww66G.jpg)

facing issue is my original message view in replied view is not getting aligned please help me out

Following is my **left view** code :--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:id="@+id/rl_message"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.cometchat.pro.uikit.ui_components.shared.cometchatAvatar.CometChatAvatar
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv_user"
        app:corner_radius="12dp"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_user"
        tools:text="Iron Man"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_user"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_user"
        android:id="@+id/cv_message_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/iv_user"
        android:background="@drawable/union_39"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp">
        <include
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            layout="@layout/message_left_reply_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/replyLayout"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/red_600"
            android:background="@drawable/cc_message_bubble_left"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/sentiment_layout"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorWhite"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/view_sentiment"
                android:text="@string/sentiment_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:id="@+id/view_sentiment"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorWhite"
                android:text="@string/view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@+id/replyLayout"
            android:id="@+id/go_txt_message"
            android:autoLink="web|all"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/cc_black"
            tools:text="tov kjnfkjn kjnfksjnfjn kjnfdjn kjnfol"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_60sdp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/_50sdp"
            android:maxWidth="@dimen/_240sdp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/worksans_regular"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/replyLayout"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="11:00 PM"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/worksans_regular"
            android:textColor="@color/cc_black"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            tools:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/go_txt_message"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_pending"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cv_message_container"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/cv_message_container"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cv_message_container"
        android:id="@+id/reaction_group"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:singleLine="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/reactions_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cv_message_container"
        android:layout_below="@+id/reaction_group"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
            android:id="@+id/thread_reply_count"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            tools:text="2 replies"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

message_left_reply_item:--

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/replyLayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:cardElevation="0dp"
android:maxWidth="200dp"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
android:visibility="gone"
tools:visibility="visible">
<ImageView
    android:src="@color/cc_black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.2"/>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:minWidth="@dimen/_100sdp"
    android:maxWidth="@dimen/_270sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/left_border_lmessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reply_user"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/_100sdp"
        android:maxWidth="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:textColor="@color/cc_black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="ls:sample k_names" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/reply_image"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cc_message_bubble_right"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reply_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:textColor="@color/cc_black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reply_user"
        tools:text="@string/replyTxt" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

the output which im getting is -->

when the text is small then original message name gets croped --> [image]

please help me...need ui just like whatsapp